# Запись файла в цикле while на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, while

Столкнулся с проблемой, в цикле while при определённых условиях, необходимо выводить информацию и записывать её в файл. С выводом информации всё хорошо, а вот файл создаётся только после выхода из цикла, что приводит к тому, что записывается только последняя информация, как сделать, чтоб запись была в каждом проходе цикла

```
while True:
    event = input('- ')
    if event.lower() in ('search', 's'):
        list_photo, value_compability = get_result(value_compability, token)
        pprint(list_photo)
        with open(f'Cache\\Топ-10 для пользователя {user_id}.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json.dump(list_photo, file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Comment: Обернул запись файла в функцию, и начало работать как надо.

Answer (score 5):

Все не так! Файл создается при каждом проходе цикла. Просто он каждый раз затирается новыми данными и в конце остаются только самые последние. Возможные решения:

1. Вынести открытие файлы за пределы цикла.
2. Изменить режим открытия файла на "a", это будет дописывать строки в конец файла, а не переписывать уже имеющиеся.

Comment: В том то и дело, что именно так мне и надо, чтоб я не вышел из цикла, а файл уже был,  а с каждой итерацией данные затирались новыми, но получается именно как писал, файл появляется именно после выхода из цикла, и то что там было на промежуточной итерации я просмотреть не могу, только последняя, только после завершения программы

Comment: Тогда вам нужно добавить кода в вопрос, чтобы любой, кто захочет посмотреть, что происходит, мог просто скопировать и запустить, не ломая голову над тем, что нужно еще добавить, чтобы скрипт работал.