# неправильная запись в файл, засписывается только последнее значение

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять, не варит на ночь глядя бошка вообще. Смысл в том, что использую f строки, с помощью них создаётся 6 файлов типа `result2_hostname1` `result2_hostname2` `result2_hostname3` и т.д. В каждом из этих файлов есть строки. Хочу взять все эти файлы, и объединить в один.
С помощью моего варианта скрипта, в конечном виде в `print(line)` вижу всё как я хотел, а когда делаю `f_out.write(line)` записывается только результат последнего файла, т.е. строки из `result2_hostname6`.
Нужны все строки во всех файлах, в одном конечном.
Вариант моего скрипта:

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
file = open('C:/Users/sx01/Desktop/Python3/13/new/hosts.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    info = {}
    info['ip'], info['hostname'], *_ = line.split()

    try:
        with open(f'C:/Users/sx01/Desktop/Python3/13/new/result2_{info["hostname"]}') as f_in, open(f'C:/Users/sx01/Desktop/Python3/13/new/result_good','w') as f_out:
            for line in f_in:
                print(line)
                f_out.write(line)

    except Exception as e:
        error_log = str(e)
        print('error_log')

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что результат print() остаётся на экране навсегда, а флаг w при открытии файла говорит о том, что каждый раз содержимое файла перезаписывется.

Так что запись в файл правильная. Нужно просто использовать правильный режим работы с файлом.

Ещё на тему

[Запись файла в цикле while на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131220/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-while-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python/1131225)